# how to read large YAML file in golang?

Tags: go, yaml

Is there any memory-efficient way to read large YAML files in Golang, like is there any way to read **YAML file** in chunks in go lang

Comment: There are Go libraries that parse YAML. Have you tried any? Did you encounter problems? If so, please provide an example and describe what didn't work.

Comment: I am new in Golang, Yes I do try libraries but I think they read YAML files in one go, and I thought which makes it difficult to read large YAML files, so instead of reading the whole file in memory is there any way to read that file in small chunks.

Comment: Most parsing libraries have options to do both. Typically "Unmarshal" is used for reading some data all at once, and "Decoder" is used for reading incrementally through an `io.Reader`. For recursive formats such as YAML, however, the maximal memory footprint during parsing may depend on the actual structure of the data, not the length of it.

Comment: okay, so that means I can simply use "Decoder" for YAML files instead of "Unmarshall".
Thank you !!

Comment: Basically, yes. It's still up to the library and make a smart implementation and not use too much memory while parsing the data piece by piece. But, at least with a decoder, you're not *required* to load the whole file at once.

Comment: ` var b Index;

 file, _ := os.Open("index1.yaml");

 defer file.Close();

 dec := yaml.NewDecoder(file);

 dec.Decode(&b);
 
 walk(b.Entrie);`
so this is the only and correct way or anything else can be done over here.

Comment: You're using the correct methods to make the most of the library. For any further improvement you'd need to start rewriting the library code. So, hopefully it's good enough as it is.

Comment: How big is your YAML file and how many do you need to parse?

Comment: @gonutz it's like 17MB

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thank you, It's really helpful. can you please share some examples which contain some reimplementation of library code.

Comment: How is 17 MB a large file? Are you not working on a laptop or Desktop machine with Gigabytes of RAM? This is a serious question, I know it sounds like irony, but it is now.

Comment: I mention "rewriting the library" as something that is probably much more effort than it is worth (and beyond my ability. I assume the library authors put some good effort in already). There are probably much easier gains achievable by just switching to a simpler data format. And as gonutz mentions, 17MB is unlikely to cause any practical problem on a modern computer.

Answer (score 1):

I used Viper. Worked well for me.